# Python lambda explanation

Tags: python, lambda

I couldn't find an explanation in the python documentation about what is the difference between

```
   lambda value, _: func(value)
```

and

```
   lambda value : func(value)
```

or what the `_` is used for.

Answer (score 6):

They create two *different* `lambda` functions. The first takes two arguments, the second only takes one argument.

The `_` is just a name to indicate (by convention) that the value will be ignored. The Python language does not assign any special meaning to it.

It looks as if the `lambda` was designed to be passed to an API that *requires* a callable with two arguments.